# VBA. Using a variable to retrieve specific row on a different sheet where to take information from

Tags: excel, key, vba

I have a macro that takes a specific cell with a code (8 characters Letters + Numbers code) as a key into a variable(String). I need to use that variable to search for it in another sheet and copy some cells from that same row.

I have been trying using For and If inside, but havent been able to receive any data from it.

EDIT: Edit with the code I'm trying, tho I think its not even close to correct and I'll have to try something totally different.

```
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Set ws1 = Worksheets("Hoja1")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("ErrorGuide")
Set rng = ws2.Range("B2:B151")
For Each cell In rng
MsgBox cell

    If ErrorNumber = ws2.Range(Celladdress) Then

    Let CurrentNumber = Value(actualrow, 4)

        Cells(actualrow, 9).Value = CurrentNumber

    End If
Next cell
```

Comment: Help us to help you.... **post your current code**

Comment: Do you know what row or column you need to search in?

Comment: Yes, the code I need to compare is in the second column, and the data I want to copy is in the forth.

Comment: Is current number the string you need to search?

Comment: No, the string I need to search in the second Sheet is ErrorNumber, On my mind, "CurrentNumber" is the variable to compare to ErrorNumber every time

Comment: Your code doesn't show ErrorNumber anywhere?

Comment: You seem to have a lot of variables that do not have any declaration or assignment. `ErrorNumber`, `Celladdress` and `actualrow`, as far as I can see.